# regular expression cannot match var*num and num*var

Tags: regex

I want to match the expression of var * var, var * num, num * var and num * num separately, i.e. using four different regular expression.
my var could be s1,s2,...,S1,S2,...,v1,v2,...V1,V2....
my num could be any float number

for `var*var`, I use:

```
[vVsS][0-9]+\s*[*/]\s*[vVsS][0-9]+
```

and it works well

for `var*num` and `num*var`, I use:

```
[vVsS][0-9]+\s*[*/]\s*[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*
```

and

```
[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*\s*[*/]\s*(vVsS)[0-9]+
```

but it returns nothing when I try the input:

```
2*4 + s1* 7  + v3 * 2 + s3 * V2 + 5*v1
```

UPDATE: I could do that now.
For example, for the case of var * num 
`[vVsS][0-9]+\s*[*/]\s*[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?` works well, as Wiktor Stribiżew suggests in comment.
But I didn't find some explanation on the use of(?:) online. Anyone has idea on that?

Comment: And what do you expect? See [`[vVsS]?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?\s*[*/]\s*[vVsS]?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/aQ4gR5/1) - is that what you seek?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, since you tagged it as MATLAB, please add the ***MATLAB*** syntax (with example input) that you used to implement the expression you posted above

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribizew, I would like to match different cases separately. But I have made it from the hints of your regular expression. The problem of the RE you post might be that it will recognize V1.5 as well. I have read the link you provide carefully, but I am still confused with (?:), what's the use of that?

Comment: Please do not use spaces between `@` and username, or I would not have been notified (I was just on this page by chance). I do not understand what you need, please clarify by providing exact inputs and expected outputs (or what must be matched what not).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, like the input I include in my problem: 2*4 + s1* 7  + v3 * 2 + s3 * V2 + 5*v1, I would like it to recognize the case of num*num, var*num, num*var, var*var. I want them separately, so I need 4 different RE. For number, it is float: 2.3453, 23 etc. For variable, the allowed cases are that s1,s2,...,S1,S2,...,v1,v2,...V1,V2..... For this problem, I have already figured out from the RE you provide. I just don't understand the use of (?:[.][0-9]+)? in your RE.

Comment: Ok, judging by your edit `[vVsS][0-9]+\s*[*/]\s*[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?` works for you. I will add an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[vVsS][0-9]+\s*[*/]\s*[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `[vVsS][0-9]+` - a letter from the character class (either `v`, `V`, `s` or `S`) followed with one or more digits
- `\s*[*/]\s*` - a `/` or `*` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.][0-9]+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a dot and one or more digits.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering what's the difference with ([.][0-9]+)? and (?:[.][0-9]+)?

Comment: The first one captures the value into a Group 1 buffer, the second one does not.